# Creating Facebook app that records engagements with page and website

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps

I'm not sure if fb regulations would allow this, but is it possible to create an fb app which users to log into, which from then on records all their shares and interactions on my facebook page and website shares, to give users a score of how engaged they are and reward them for that?

Answer (score 0):

This is the whole list of data you can listen for: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/reference/user/

Be aware that rewarding users for shares and stuff is not allowed according to the platform policy.